# Encountering 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'memes')' upon attempting to upload a file using ng-upload in Angular

Tags: html, .net, angular, typescript

I am struggling with this for a while now. I am trying to upload an image using ng-upload in angular, the file is saved in the database, however I am receiving 'Cannot read properties of undefined' when the upload queue is over. Code used for receiving the file:

Upload.html

```
 <div class="container text-center" *ngIf="memeUploadMode">
        <div class="row mt-3">
 
            <div class="col-md-3">
        
                <h3>Dodaj mema</h3>
        
                <div ng2FileDrop
                     [ngClass]="{'nv-file-over': hasBaseDropzoneOver}"
                     (fileOver)="fileOverBase($event)"
                     [uploader]="uploader"
                     class="card bg-faded p-3 text-center mb-3 my-drop-zone">
                     <i class="fa fa-upload fa-3x"></i>
                    Przeciągnij mema tutaj
                </div>
        
                <input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-bottom: 40px" *ngIf="uploader?.queue?.length">
        
                <h3>Kolejka</h3>
                <p>Długość kolejki: {{ uploader?.queue?.length }}</p>
        
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="50%">Nazwa</th>
                        <th>Rozmiar</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of uploader.queue">
                        <td><strong>{{ item?.file?.name }}</strong></td>
                        <td *ngIf="uploader.options.isHTML5" nowrap>{{ item?.file?.size/1024/1024 | number:'.2' }} MB</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
        
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Queue progress:
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': uploader.progress + '%' }"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s"
                            (click)="uploader.uploadAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
                        <span class="fa fa-upload"></span> Upload all
                    </button>
                </div>
        
            </div>
    </div>
```

And here's the code where I'm trying to add the image to the member object:

Upload.ts

```
constructor(public accountService: AccountService, private memberService: MembersService,
    private router: Router, private toastr: ToastrService) { 
      this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(user => this.user = user);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeUploader();
  }

  fileOverBase(e: any) {
    this.hasBaseDropzoneOver = e;
  } 

  deletePhoto(photoId: number) {
    this.memberService.deletePhoto(photoId).subscribe(() => {
      this.member.photos = this.member.photos.filter(x => x.id !== photoId);
    })
  }

  initializeUploader() {
    this.uploader = new FileUploader({
      url: this.baseUrl + 'users/add-meme',
      authToken: 'Bearer ' + this.user.token,
      isHTML5: true,
      allowedFileType: ['image'],
      removeAfterUpload: true,
      autoUpload: false,
      maxFileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024
    });

    this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => {
      file.withCredentials = false;
    }

    this.uploader.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status, headers) => {
      if (response) {
        const meme: Meme = JSON.parse(response);
        this.member.memes.push(meme);
           this.user.memeUrl = meme.url;
           this.member.memeUrl = meme.url;
           this.accountService.setCurrentUser(this.user);
      }
    }
  }

    memeToggle() {
        this.memeUploadMode = !this.memeUploadMode;
    }
```

The error occurs at this line:

```
   this.member.memes.push(meme);
```

I've already looked at similar questions, however none of the answers helped me. I must add that I already have a similar feature for adding user's photos, which is set up identically and it works. Any help would be much appreaciated.

Cheers,
Filip

Comment: it doesnt appear that you have `member` defined in your code, or you did not add that line in the example.

Comment: It is defined in the interface, sorry about not mentioning it. I don't know how to past code in the comments properly.

Comment: export interface Member {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    photoUrl: string;
    memeUrl: string;
    age: number;
    created: Date;
    lastActive: Date;
    gender: string;
    photos: Photo[];
    memes: Meme[];
    likes: number;
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define `member` in your component

```
member = {
  memes: [],
  memeUrl: ''
};
```

Comment: Hi there. You mean apart from defining it in the interface? As it already was defined, sorry for not posting that.

Comment: the interface is just for the typescript compiler, when you define a interface it does not create a class or a reference to a variable. you still need to define that variable in your class component.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, right. I see. I had those in my Upload.ts file when the error occured:

```
@Input() member: Member;
  members: Member[];
  memes: Meme[] = [];
  model: any = {}
  uploader: FileUploader;
```

After defining the member as you suggested, the compiler asked me to define every other attribute as well. Now it works, you are my savior, my good Sir :)